# How can I find the density function of Z?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

I am trying to find the density function for Z, this is what I am doing but I am not getting an appropiate function, I don´t know if there is something wrong with limits of the intregral. Or if this is not the correct approach. I have that $f(x)=ax^{a-1}$ for $0<x<1$ and $a>0$ and X and Y are iid, so I say that  $f(y)=ay^{a-1}$ and $f(x,y)=a^2x^{a-1}y^{a-1}$ 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The limits of the inner integral should be between 0 and $\min(Z/Y,1)$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes, it does.  He has a problem with his integral, suggested that the limits might be wrong.  I believe they are wrong, and said what I think they should be.

Comment: could you add some explanation then as to why the limits are what you claim them to be, i.e. expand on your answer a little bit? Cheers